# Keycloak Policy Enforcement Springboot

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak, keycloak-services

I am implementing Keycloak scope based permission authentication in Spring-boot application. I am using Keycloak.json file to initialize Keycloak adapter and now I applied policy in Keycloak.json file and while testing API I am getting **error : failed to obtain policy enforcer**
and below is my Keycloak.json file :

```
{
   "realm": "XYZ",
   "auth-server-url": "<auth-url>",
   "ssl-required": "none",
   "resource": "dashboard",
   "verify-token-audience": true,
   "credentials": {
     "secret": "<client-secret>"
   },
   "confidential-port": 0,
   "policy-enforcer": {
     "user-managed-access" : {},
     "enforcement-mode" : "ENFORCING",
     "paths": [
       {
         "name" : "Resource",
         "path" : "/*",
         "methods" : [
           {
             "method": "POST",
             "scopes" : ["post"]
           },
           {
             "method": "PUT",
             "scopes" : ["put"]
           }
         ]
       }
     ]
   }
}
```

Exception : java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to obtain policy enforcer at org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment.getPolicyEnforcer(KeycloakDeployment.java:539)
~[keycloak-adapter-core-11.0.3.jar:11.0.3] at org.keycloak.adapters.AuthenticatedActionsHandler.isAuthorized(AuthenticatedActionsHandler.java:150)
~[keycloak-adapter-core-11.0.3.jar:11.0.3]at org.keycloak.adapters.AuthenticatedActionsHandler.handledRequest(AuthenticatedActionsHandler.java:60)
~[keycloak-adapter-core-11.0.3.jar:11.0.3] org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment.getPolicyEnforcer(KeycloakDeployment.java:537)
~[keycloak-adapter-core-11.0.3.jar:11.0.3] Caused by: org.keycloak.jose.jws.JWSInputException:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.split(String)" because "wire" is null at org.keycloak.jose.jws.JWSInput.(JWSInput.java:58)
org.keycloak.authorization.client.util.TokenCallable.call(TokenCallable.java:64) Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke
"String.split(String)" because "wire" is null at org.keycloak.jose.jws.JWSInput.(JWSInput.java:44) ~[keycloak-core-11.0.3.jar:11.0.3]

Comment: It'd be very helpful to see the full stacktrace of the `failed to obtain policy enforcer` error.

Comment: @dekkard I added stacktrace pls check. I am not able to identified the issue from this.

Comment: From the code it looks like your keycloak doesn't return refreshToken ("refresh_token" in the json response) when your client requests a token.

Comment: @dekkard Thanks for the response I just checked and you are right I don't get refresh token. so can you help me with the reason, why this is happening.

Comment: What are the query params in the token request that your client sends to the Keycloak? At least, what's the grant_type ?

Comment: @dekkard the grant type is password and the refresh token issue is resolved after updating keycloak adapter version to 17 but now I am getting below given error :                    
" [http-nio-38080-exec-1] DEBUG o.k.a.authorization.PolicyEnforcer - Policy enforcement result for path [http://localhost:8080/api/test] is : DENIED
[http-nio-38080-exec-1] DEBUG o.k.a.authorization.PolicyEnforcer - Returning authorization context with permissions:    "                                                                        
so can you help me with the reason, why this is happening.

Comment: Try with explicit path `/api/test` in your policy-enforcer.paths.path